# Rails create multiple action how to also create associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my controller I have:

```
def create_multiple
  @taletid = Taletid.find(params[:taletid_ids])
  if params[:delete_button]
   delete_multiple(params)
  else
  @taletid.each do |taletid|
  Taletid.create(taletid.attributes)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(:admin_taletids, :notice => "Konkurrancerne er nu slettet") }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

There is a `has_and_belongs_to_many` to relation ship between taltids and pakkes

But the action do not creates any associations that the orginial taletid had.

How to create the associations for the new objects?

Comment: Please elaborate a little more, we have no idea about your associations :), neither the two actions you mentioned above. Remember to frame the question as much as informative and simple.

Comment: I have updated the question with the relation ship : )

Answer (score 0):

If it is a many-to-many relationship there is a join table and attributes are not associated with the associations.

You may try.

```
@taletid.each do |taletid|
  t = Taletid.new(taletid.attributes)
  t.pakkes += taletid.pakkes
  t.save
end
```